# Change space between fontawesome list icon and text

Tags: list, sass

Is it possible to change the space between the icon and the text without any `<span>` elements and just css?

My sass for a standard list:

```
ul {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
        &:before {    
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        content: '\f0da';
        margin:0 0.5rem 1rem -2rem;
        color: $color-leuchterred;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: changing the margin right in `&:before`:  `margin:0 3rem 1rem -2rem;`

Comment: Can you create a sample case in Codepen or similar ? With the font imported... all the variables in the sass if needed etc...

Answer (score 0):

add an en space character in your content - scroll down to Punctuation
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

```
ul {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    padding-left: 3rem;
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
        &:before {    
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        content: '\f0da\2002';
        margin:0 0.5rem 1rem -2rem;
        color: $color-leuchterred;
        }
    }
}
```